# Эмуляция EOF с клавиатуры, линукс, си

Tags: linux, c, ubuntu, clion, stdin

Пишу программу на чистом Си в операционной системе Убунту 19.10

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    int ch = 0;
    while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF)
        putchar(ch);
    printf("\nOK\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Программа читает символы вводимые с клавиатуры и выводит на экран при вводе символа новой строки. В учебнике для эмуляции конца файла с клавиатуры рекомендуют попробовать комбинацию Ctrl-D в начале новой строки. Но если так делать, то записи OK не выводится, программа просто прекращает работу. Как правильно эмулировать конец файла? Среда программирования Clion

Comment: Не выводится или закрывается окно и вы просто не успеваете этого заметить?

Comment: Именно не выводится. Никакое окно не закрывается, потому что ввод и вывод осуществляются в специальном поле среды разработки, а не в консоли https://b.radikal.ru/b08/2002/5e/658d3c9a40f5.png

Comment: Может эта среда сама и закрывает свой поток. Прога у вас рабочая. Проверьте в консоли.

Comment: @Виктор если запускать не в среде разработки, то после Ctrl+D всё замечательно выводится https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2HED.png

Comment: Значит, конец файла отслеживает среда разработки и прерывает работу. Видимо, так. Но программа-то предназначена для работы не в среде? :) Еще вариант - в командной строке перенаправить ввод из файла, кстати.